Service Fabric - parametrized name
I want to parameterize Service Fabric service name for default stateful project.
My Service Fabric application: TestApp
My Service Fabric stateful service: TestStatefulService
I want to deploy it with parameterized name instead of TestStatefulService.
I tried to achieve it by exending StartupServices.xml with new parameter "TestStatefulService_NewName" and use it as service name, as follow:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StartupServicesManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_MinReplicaSetSize" DefaultValue="3" />
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="1" />
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_TargetReplicaSetSize" DefaultValue="3" />
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_NewName" DefaultValue="NewNameParam" />
  </Parameters>
  <Services>
    <Service Name="[TestStatefulService_NewName]" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="TestStatefulServiceType" TargetReplicaSetSize="[TestStatefulService_TargetReplicaSetSize]" MinReplicaSetSize="[TestStatefulService_MinReplicaSetSize]">
        <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[TestStatefulService_PartitionCount]" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
      </StatefulService>
    </Service>
  </Services>
</StartupServicesManifest>

and I overrided Cloud.xml to add new param:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StartupServices xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_PartitionCount" Value="1" />
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="TestStatefulService_NewName" Value="NewDeployName123" />
  </Parameters>
</StartupServices>

I publish the app via Visual Studio ("Publish" option) and it throws an error:
"2>New-ServiceFabricService : Failed to parse the requested Naming URI: fabric:/TestApp/[TestStatefulService_NewName]
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Utilities.ps1:742 char:4
2>+             New-ServiceFabricService -Stateful -HasPersistedState -Pa ...
2>+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [New-ServiceFabr
2>   icService], FabricException
2>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateServiceErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.NewService"
I would be grateful to any hints ! Thanks in advance
